# Is this a known issue in 12.3.1 with GridLinesStyle with Dashed option not working?

Tags: plotting, style, grid-lines

**Update Dec 7**, 2021. Reported to WRI. A support case was created with the ID [**CASE:4883278**].

---

According to [help](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLinesStyle.html)

---

[image]

But the above no longer works in 12.3.1 (windows 10)

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10},
 Ticks -> {None, Automatic},
 GridLines -> {{Pi, 2 Pi, 3 Pi}, {-1, -.5, .5, 1}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]
 ]
```

Is there a way to make it work in 12.3.1 as it shows in help?

**ps**. Trying the above on 12.2, it worked OK. Same output as help. So it seems something changed in V 12.3 ?

Comment: It looks OK (as shown in Help) on my system, version 12.3.1, Win 10 Home. Also, I am running a laptop with a 4K display.

Comment: @david  I do not have 4k display. You think it is related to what monitor one uses?

Comment: Perhaps on your system, the `AbsoluteDashing` has been set elsewhere? I have 12.2.0 so mine prints ok.

Comment: @Syed  I do not set AbsoluteDashing anywhere. I also closed Mathematica and started it again, and the problem is still there. Windows 10 pro PC running standard monitor (not 4k)

Comment: I've got the same problem (standard monitor and Windows 10), but ``Dashing[0.003]`` works for me.

Comment: @E.Chan-López thanks. Could you please post this as answer for a workaround showing how you used Dashing in the above example?

Comment: Of course, I do it!

Comment: @Nasser I offer you an apology because I misunderstood your request. :-)

Comment: Some problem in version 12.3.0 But the following works: `Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, 
 GridLines -> {{Pi, 2 Pi, 3 Pi}, {-1, -.5, .5, 1}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed, Dashing[0.003]]]`

Comment: @Nasser I don't know if it is related. But since version 12.1, the front end handles displays differently than before. Possibly, 12.3.1 was tweaked and that introduced the issue on standard displays (not HDPI displays)? John Fulz discussed the 12.1 changes in a Tech Conf video. [link](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?sx=front%20end&v=2835)

Comment: @Nasser, feel free to report it.  It's a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version
(*12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)*)
```

The following change works for me:

```
Graphics[Circle[], Axes -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashing[0.003]]]
(*Dashing instead Dashed*)
```

[image]